# Screen views in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Just want to know where in Google Analytics can show the screen views of the mobile app. I cannot find them >.< Where to click to go which screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Behaviour => Screens

That's it.

Comment: There are no Sreens under Behavhiour